# Issue converting Base 64 to Bitmap in Kotlin - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, base64, android-bitmap

I am using below method to convert Base64 Image to Bitmap:

```
fun convertString64ToImage(base64String: String): Bitmap {
   val decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String)
   return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.size)
}
```

But Unfortunately getting error as below:

**Illegal base64 character a**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.myapp.app, PID: 27391
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character a
> at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
> at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
> at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
> at com.myapp.sdk.view.BaseActivity$Utility.convertString64ToImage(BaseActivity.kt:201)
> at com.myapp.sdk.view.document.ScanActivity.setResultToView(ScanActivity.kt:426)
> at com.myapp.sdk.view.document.ScanActivity.completion$lambda-3(DocumentScanActivity.kt:274)
> at com.myapp.sdk.view.document.ScanActivity.$r8$lambda$mFUznctDAtk-c_-MzvUsX70AtrY(Unknown Source:0)

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong class. 
You need to use `android.util.Base64` instead of `java.util.Base64`. Then call `Base64.decode()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android.util.Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT)` to get decrypted string.

Comment: *to get decrypted string* - you mean decoded, there's nothing encrypted here.